# What is the maximum number of overs that can be bowled with one ball in Test cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

What is the maximum number of overs with the same ball in a cricket test match.  I have asked this question on google and not given satisfactory answer, could you please advise of law.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit. So long as the ball is fit for play, any number of overs (in one innings; the ball is always replaced at the start of every innings<sup>1</sup>) may be bowled with it should the fielding captain wish to do so. However, should a ball which is more than 110 overs old become unfit for play, it *must* be replaced with a new ball; quoting from [Law 4.5 of the current Test Match playing conditions](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2018/09/27/061adf29-5cf7-486b-858b-ca5ad6bde935/03-Mens-Test-Match-Playing-Conditions-2018.pdf):

> If, during play, the ball cannot be found or recovered or the umpires
>   agree that it has become unfit for play through normal use, the
>   umpires shall replace it with a ball which has had wear comparable
>   with that which the previous ball had received before the need for its
>   replacement. When the ball is replaced, the umpires shall inform the
>   batsmen and the fielding captain.
>
> However, if the ball needs to be replaced after 110 overs for any of the
>   reasons above, it shall be replaced by a new ball. If the ball is to be
>   replaced, the umpires shall inform the batsmen, the fielding captain and
>   the scorers.

The second paragraph here is an addition to the [general Law 4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-ball). This change to the playing conditions occurred after a couple of incidents where teams *did* want to carry on bowling with an very old ball; once the old ball went out of shape, it practically became almost impossible to find a ball "which has had wear comparable with that which the previous ball had received".

<sup>1. This is a theoretical difference between the general Laws and the Test Match playing conditions; [see this answer for more details](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/20659/6126).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the Bowling Team and Umpires. But generally, a new ball is available after **80 overs** are bowled in a test match.
Following are the possible ways a ball is changed in a test match.

1. Ball is Lost
2. The condition of the Ball is not good (physical damage or tempered)
3. Bowling Team opted for a new ball after bowling 80 overs.

In all the cases on-field umpires are the action takers. And umpires do discussions with both the captain or bowling team captain and two onfield batsman.

Answer (score -3):

Depends on the pitch conditions, bowling styles, batting styles, power hitters like Gayle, Sehwag would make the ball last for less than 100 overs